# How can create an array based on value of variables?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to turn in the below function values of cell into array. How can I turn it into array format? Thanks in advance.

```
function cellist() {
  

   var cell = '';
  var sel = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSelection().getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
  for(var i = 0; i < sel.length; i++){
    cell += sel[i].getA1Notation() + ', ';
  }


}
```

Turning values into array format.

Comment: Do you mean `cell`.  Rather than comma seperated list array of A1 notations?

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunk() {
  let a = 1;
  let b = 2;
  let c = 3;
  let arr = [a,b,c];
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
}

Execution log
11:26:39 AM Notice  Execution started
11:26:37 AM Info    [1,2,3]
11:26:40 AM Notice  Execution completed
```